# Git bash acting weird in intellij-idea

Tags: java, bash, git, intellij-idea

managed to put GIT bash to intellij idea. it starts well from IDE but not recognizing any git bash commands as well as java commands.
throws "**bash: java: command not found**"
git bash works perfectly when lunched **not** from IDE. weird part that they both have the same path to the same .exe file.

Comment: The terminal run inside your IDE seems to miss the directory to `your_java_installation/bin` from its `PATH` variable. That's why you get `bash: java: command not found`.

Comment: Could you please check what path do you have under Preferences | Version Control | Git
What output would you get if you run "Test" next to a path to Git executables?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe  
when I run "Test" it says: "Git version is 2.30.1"

Answer (score 0):

Git is automatically managed by the IntelliJ idea which does not require any additional commands. All happens via button click.

Git basic operations:

[image]

Now if you don't have these options. Then go to VCS > Enable version control integration and select git. Then these options will come on toolbar.

Comment: Got these options but it didn`t solve the problem. Still not recognizing neither git or java commands.